# What is the canonical way to trim a string in Ruby without creating a new string?

Tags: ruby, string

This is what I have now - which looks too verbose for the work it is doing.

```
@title        = tokens[Title].strip! || tokens[Title] if !tokens[Title].nil?
```

Assume tokens is a array obtained by splitting a CSV line.
now the functions like strip! chomp! et. all return nil if the string was not modified

```
"abc".strip!    # => nil
" abc ".strip!  # => "abc"
```

What is the Ruby way to say trim it if it contains extra leading or trailing spaces without creating copies?

Gets uglier if I want to do `tokens[Title].chomp!.strip!`

Comment: If you're going to be reading things out of tokens repeatedly, it might make more sense to pre-process it. I.e., " tokens.each {|t| t.strip!} ". then you can just do " @title = tokens[Title] || '' "

Answer (score 309, accepted):

I guess what you want is:

```
@title = tokens[Title]
@title.strip!
```

The [`#strip!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-strip) method will return `nil` if it didn't strip anything, and the variable itself if it was stripped.

According to Ruby standards, a method suffixed with an exclamation mark changes the variable in place.

**Update:** This is output from `irb` to demonstrate:

```
>> @title = "abc"
=> "abc"
>> @title.strip!
=> nil
>> @title
=> "abc"
>> @title = " abc "
=> " abc "
>> @title.strip!
=> "abc"
>> @title
=> "abc"
```

Comment: Hmm.. still I think @title = tokens[Title].strip! looks cleaner - its a pity it returns nil instead of the unmodified string. Unless someone posts a better ans.. you're getting the accepted bit.

Comment: Well, @title = tokens[Title].strip will do the trick but you'd have a copy instead, which is fine if you keep the tokens[Title] variable untouched.

Comment: If you want a method to return the unmodified string, you could easily make your own: def strip_returning_self() strip! || self end

Comment: @chuck Yeah. but I was hoping there was a neat trick to do that without rolling my own method.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 has tap, which does exactly what you want:
@title.tap{|x| x.strip!}

Comment: @timkay Would it be possible to do `@title.tap &:strip!`? That seems cleaner than anything else.

Comment: Why in the world would it return `nil` unless it strips something? That has no doubt confused a ton of people (since it makes no sense).

Comment: @JoeAtzberger Any idea which version of Ruby this bogusness is removed in?

Comment: @JoshPinter deleted my comment that newer versions addressed this, since I could not verify on ruby 2.1.2 or 2.2.0.

Comment: @JoeAtzberger Thanks for following-up. Couldn't find it either so wanted to double check. Surprised it's still in there, to be honest.

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting such an old discussion... But how is `@title.tap &:strip!` clearer/cleaner than `@title.strip!`?

Answer (score 61):

Btw, now ruby already supports just strip without "!".

Compare:

```
p "abc".strip! == " abc ".strip!  # false, because "abc".strip! will return nil
p "abc".strip == " abc ".strip    # true
```

Also it's impossible to `strip` without duplicates. See sources in string.c:

```
static VALUE
rb_str_strip(VALUE str)
{
    str = rb_str_dup(str);
    rb_str_strip_bang(str);
    return str;
}
```

*ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]*

Update 1:
As I see now -- it was created in 1999 year (see [rev #372](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/string.c?r1=11&r2=372&diff_format=h) in SVN):

Update2:
`strip!` will not create duplicates — both in 1.9.x, 2.x and trunk versions.

Comment: "it's impossible to stripping without duplicates" - of course it's possible, that's what `strip!` is for.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath dont' you see the source code, written in C? Pls read carefully, what I written here regarding duplicates.

Comment: Of course i see it. But that's the source code of `strip`. Am I misunderstand something? How else could I interpret "impossible to stripping without duplicate"?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath internally duplicate is always created. That's about string `    str = rb_str_dup(str);`

Comment: And if you don't want a duplicate, you use `strip!` aka `rb_str_strip_bang`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I see now, what do you mean. I've used bad term "stripping". I mean there only "strip" and not "strip!". So I added note about bang-version.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Ruby on Rails there is a **squish**

```
> @title = " abc "
 => " abc " 

> @title.squish
 => "abc"
> @title
 => " abc "

> @title.squish!
 => "abc"
> @title
 => "abc"
```

If you are using just Ruby you want to use **strip**

Herein lies the gotcha.. in your case you want to use strip without the bang !

while strip! certainly does return nil if there was no action it still updates the variable so strip! cannot be used inline. If you want to use strip inline you can use the version without the bang !

**strip!** using multi line approach

```
> tokens["Title"] = " abc "
 => " abc "
> tokens["Title"].strip!
 => "abc"
> @title = tokens["Title"]
 => "abc"
```

**strip** single line approach... YOUR ANSWER

```
> tokens["Title"] = " abc "
 => " abc "
> @title = tokens["Title"].strip if tokens["Title"].present?
 => "abc"
```

Answer (score 10):

There's no need to both strip and chomp as strip will also remove trailing carriage returns - unless you've changed the default record separator and that's what you're chomping.

Olly's answer already has the canonical way of doing this in Ruby, though if you find yourself doing this a lot you could always define a method for it:

```
def strip_or_self!(str)
  str.strip! || str
end
```

Giving:

```
@title = strip_or_self!(tokens[Title]) if tokens[Title]
```

Also keep in mind that the if statement will prevent `@title` from being assigned if the token is nil, which will result in it keeping its previous value. If you want or don't mind `@title` always being assigned you can move the check into the method and further reduce duplication:

```
def strip_or_self!(str)
  str.strip! || str if str
end
```

As an alternative, if you're feeling adventurous you can define a method on String itself:

```
class String
  def strip_or_self!
    strip! || self
  end
end
```

Giving one of:

```
@title = tokens[Title].strip_or_self! if tokens[Title]

@title = tokens[Title] && tokens[Title].strip_or_self!
```

Comment: Or just use `tokens[Title].try(&:strip)`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use another method after you need something like this:

```
( str.strip || str ).split(',')
```

This way you can strip and still do something after :)

Comment: More likely `str.split(',').map(&:strip)`

Answer (score 4):

I think your example is a sensible approach, although you could simplify it slightly as:

```
@title = tokens[Title].strip! || tokens[Title] if tokens[Title]
```

Alternative you could put it on two lines:

```
@title = tokens[Title] || ''
@title.strip!
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have either ruby 1.9 or activesupport, you can do simply

```
@title = tokens[Title].try :tap, &:strip!
```

This is really cool, as it leverages the `:try` and the `:tap` method, which are the most powerful functional constructs in ruby, in my opinion.

An even cuter form, passing functions as symbols altogether:

```
@title = tokens[Title].send :try, :tap, &:strip!
```

Answer (score 1):

My way:

```
> (@title = " abc ").strip!
 => "abc" 
> @title
 => "abc"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@title = tokens[Title].strip! || tokens[Title]
```

It's entirely possible i'm not understanding the topic, but wouldn't this do what you need?

```
" success ".strip! || "rescue" #=> "success"
"failure".strip! || "rescue" #=> "rescue"
```