# How to remove mysterious whitespace from line breaks in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails application I have a field `address` which is a `varchar(255)` in my SQLite database.

Yet whenever I save an address consisting of more than one line through a `textarea` form field, one mysterious whitespace character gets added to the right.

This becomes visible only when the address is right aligned (like e.g. on a letterhead).

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how it can be prevented?

I am not doing anything special with those addresses in my model.

I already added this attribute writer to my model but it won't remove the whitespace unfortunately:

```
def address=(a)
  write_attribute(:address, a.strip)
end
```

This is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see only the last line is right aligned. All others contain one character of whitespace at the end.

---

**Edit:**

This would be the HTML output from my (Safari) console:

```
<p>
  "John Doe "<br>
  "123 Main Street "<br>
  "Eggham "<br>
  "United Kingdom"<br>
</p>
```

I don't even know why it's putting the quotes around each line... Maybe that's part of the solution?

Comment: Can you please show us an example of this whitespace?

Comment: I added a screenshot above.

Comment: Wait, textarea means you have multiple lines correct?  That means displaying each line you need to `split` by a line break.  Then strip each line.

Comment: Isn't this space the usual word separation? Or are the words being separeted by a carrier return?

Comment: @MarcoPoli: No, I didn't hit spacebar after any of those lines. I only hit return.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `textarea` is returning CR/LF for line separators and you're seeing one of these characters displayed between each line.  See [PHP displays \r\n characters when echoed in Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642535/php-displays-r-n-characters-when-echoed-in-textarea) for some discussion of this. There are probably better questions out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out the whitespace at the start and end of each line. Here are two simple techniques to do that:

```
# Using simple ruby
def address=(a)
  a = a.lines.map(&:strip).join("\n")
  write_attribute(:address, a)
end

# Using a regular expression
def address=(a)
  a = a.gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, "")
  write_attribute(:address, a)
end
```

Comment: Looks very neat, thanks. I tried both techniques but they do not change the output in any way. That's weird, isn't it?

Comment: I added some more information above. Maybe you can have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I solved a very similar kind of problem when I ran into something like this,
(I used **squish**)

```
think@think:~/CrawlFish$ irb
1.9.3-p385 :001 > "Im calling squish on a string, in irb".squish
NoMethodError: undefined method `squish' for "Im calling squish on a string, in irb":String
    from (irb):1
    from /home/think/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

That proves, there is no squish in irb(ruby)

But **rails has squish and squish!**(you should know the difference that bang(!) makes)

```
think@think:~/CrawlFish$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
1.9.3-p385 :001 > str = "Here i am\n \t \n \n, its a new world \t \t \n, its a \n \t new plan\n \r \r,do you like \r \t it?\r"
 => "Here i am\n \t \n \n, its a new world \t \t \n, its a \n \t new plan\n \r \r,do you like \r \t it?\r" 
1.9.3-p385 :002 > out = str.squish
 => "Here i am , its a new world , its a new plan ,do you like it?" 
1.9.3-p385 :003 > puts out
Here i am , its a new world , its a new plan ,do you like it?
 => nil 
1.9.3-p385 :004 >
```

Comment: It's getting sad now but `squish` doesn't work either. Tried that a few hours ago already. Thanks though!

Comment: What made you think the op wanted to remove extra spaces and tabs from the middle of a line and remove newlines?

Comment: Can I not serve the sandwhich with the ketchup?.. and I saw your solution too, it looked very beautiful and the op was very happy..

Answer (score -1):

Take a loot at `strip!` method

```
>> @title = "abc"
=> "abc"
>> @title.strip!
=> nil
>> @title
=> "abc"
>> @title = " abc "
=> " abc "
>> @title.strip!
=> "abc"
>> @title
=> "abc"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000688/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-trim-a-string-in-ruby-without-creating-a-new-string)

Answer (score -2):

What's the screen shot look like when you do:

```
def address=(a)
  write_attribute(:address, a.strip.unpack("C*").join('-') )
end
```

Update based on comment answers.  Another way to get rid of the \r's at the end of each line:

```
def address=(a)
  a = a.strip.split(/\r\n/).join("\n")  
  write_attribute(:address, a)
end
```

Comment: `74-111-104-110-32-68-111-101-13-10-49-50-51-32-77-97-105-110-32-83-116-114-101-101-116-13-10-69-103-103-104-97-109-13-10-85-110-105-116-101-100-32-75-105-110-103-100-111-109`

Comment: @Tintin81, What OS is the pdf doc being displayed on?

Comment: Mac OS 10.8.4. The browser is Safari 6.0.5. It's not a PDF. Just regular HTML.

Comment: Okay, you have Windows newlines at the end of each line `\r\n`, rather than Mac/Unix newlines `\n`, and that may be messing up your output.  However, calling strip() on each line will remove both `\r` and `\n`, so I think yfeldblum's solution should work.

Comment: By the way, the 13-10 sequences in that chain of numbers are the ascii codes for `\r\n`.  Prior to the first sequence is the ascii code 101 which represents the letter 'e', so at the end of the first line the characters are 'e\r\n'.  Before the second 13-10 sequence, is the ascii code 116, which is a 't', so the second line ends with the characters: 't\r\n'.  Before the third 13-10 sequence is the ascii code 109, which is an 'm', so the third line ends with the characters: 'm\r\n'. Finally, the last line ends with the ascii code 109, which is an 'm'.  So you can see there are no spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wish your code above worked, but unfortunately it doesn't :-( I am still getting the exact same output as before. Neither does any of yfeldblum's solutions work. I wonder why I have Windows newlines on my Mac. I haven't touched a Windows PC in years... By the way, I posted some of my HTML output above in my initial question. Have you seen it?

Comment: `I wonder why I have Windows newlines on my Mac.`  It's an html standard for textareas.  `I posted some of my HTML output above in my initial question. Have you seen it?`  Yes.  It contradicts what the chain of numbers says, but I have no idea what code outputs that html.  What I do know is that inside your address=() method, there are no spaces at the end of the lines. Are you sure you saved the file after changing the code?

Comment: You mean my `model.rb` file? Yes, I saved it! I am pretty sure!